# Set Windows Service Description in C++

Tags: c++, unmanaged

I am using `CreateService` to installs a Windows Service executable however I can't seem to find out how to set the description for the service.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Call [`ChangeServiceConfig2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988.aspx) passing `SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION` as the `dwInfoLevel` parameter. You will also need a handle to the service, but `CreateService` gives you one of those.

```
SERVICE_DESCRIPTION description = { L"The service description" };
ChangeServiceConfig2(hService, SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, &description);
```

Comment: Perfect. Spent ages trying to find this!

Comment: Worth to mention that the service has to be created with the SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG right, otherwise you'll get an "access denied" and the description will not be set.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page for an example. You use the `ChangeServiceConfig2` method.

```
SERVICE_DESCRIPTION sd;
SC_HANDLE schService;
SC_HANDLE schSCManager;

// Not shown: Get a handle to the SCM database. 
// Not shown: Get a handle to the service.

sd.lpDescription = TEXT("Description");
ChangeServiceConfig2( schService,                 // handle to service
                      SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, // change: description
                      &sd) )                      // new description
```