# Add a description to windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, registry

I installed a windows service by the following code.

```
 #region Private Variables

    #endregion Private Variables
    #region DLLImport
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string lpMachineName, string lpSCDB, int scParameter);
    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateService(IntPtr SC_HANDLE, string lpSvcName, string lpDisplayName,
    int dwDesiredAccess, int dwServiceType, int dwStartType, int dwErrorControl, string lpPathName,
    string lpLoadOrderGroup, int lpdwTagId, string lpDependencies, string lpServiceStartName, string lpPassword);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern void CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr SCHANDLE);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int StartService(IntPtr SVHANDLE, int dwNumServiceArgs, string lpServiceArgVectors);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr SCHANDLE, string lpSvcName, int dwNumServiceArgs);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int DeleteService(IntPtr SVHANDLE);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetLastError();
    #endregion DLLImport
    public static bool  InstallService(string svcPath, string svcName, string svcDispName)
    {
        #region Constants declaration.
        int SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE = 0x0002;
        int SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010;
        //int SERVICE_DEMAND_START = 0x00000003;
        int SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL = 0x00000001;
        int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
        int SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG = 0x0001;
        int SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG = 0x0002;
        int SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS = 0x0004;
        int SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS = 0x0008;
        int SERVICE_START = 0x0010;
        int SERVICE_STOP = 0x0020;
        int SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE = 0x0040;
        int SERVICE_INTERROGATE = 0x0080;
        int SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL = 0x0100;
        int SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
        SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG |
        SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG |
        SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS |
        SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS |
        SERVICE_START |
        SERVICE_STOP |
        SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE |
        SERVICE_INTERROGATE |
        SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL);
        int SERVICE_AUTO_START = 0x00000002;
        #endregion Constants declaration.
        try
        {
            IntPtr sc_handle = OpenSCManager(null, null, SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
            if (sc_handle.ToInt32() != 0)
            {
                IntPtr sv_handle = CreateService(sc_handle, svcName, svcDispName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, svcPath, null, 0, null, null, null);
                if (sv_handle.ToInt32() == 0)
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(sc_handle);
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //now trying to start the service
                    int i = StartService(sv_handle, 0, null);
                    // If the value i is zero, then there was an error starting the service.
                    // note: error may arise if the service is already running or some other problem.
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Couldnt start service");
                        return false;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Service started successfully");
                    CloseServiceHandle(sc_handle);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SCM not opened successfully");
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

But the description is blank in SCM, please don't use ServiceInsatller since I want to modify the existing code in production. Thanks for code contribution.

**UPDATE:**

If forget the above code and use ManagedInstallerClass or other methods, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original answer is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684306/set-windows-service-description-in-c), and repeated here for convenience.

> Call [`ChangeServiceConfig2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988.aspx) passing SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION as the
>   dwInfoLevel parameter. You will also need a handle to the service, but
>   [`CreateService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives you one of those.

As far the `DllImport` goes, you can find the specification for `ChangeServiceConfig2` [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/changeserviceconfig2.html).

**EDIT:**

If you want to abandon the existing approach altogether, using [`ManagedInstallerClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.managedinstallerclass%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not the right way to go because MSDN explicitly says not to use it in your code.  The correct way, in my estimation, is to use the [`ServiceInstaller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) component, but your original question said you didn't want to use that approach.

Let's say you relented on not using `ServiceInstaller`.  Then I would suggest following the instructions that I provided in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803), paying particular attention to steps 6-9.  In step #8, you can add whatever description you like to the `ServiceInstaller` component in the property grid.

If you still don't want to do that approach, then my original answer stands.  It would look something like this (mind you, I have not tested this):

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ChangeServiceConfig2(
    IntPtr hService, 
    int dwInfoLevel,
    IntPtr lpInfo);

int SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION = 0x01;
ChangeServiceConfig2(sv_handle, SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, "a test description");
```

Comment: I am thinking if using ManagedInstallerClass rather than the old fashion, how can I add service name, display name and description?

Comment: Count me confused.  MSDN says `ManagedInstallerClass` should **not** be used directly from production code.  And in your original question, you said you didn't want to use the `ServiceInstaller`, and the example shows the old-fashioned way of doing it, namely via p/invoke.  It's unclear what you're wanting, at least to me.

Comment: /@Mattsorry about it. Although my question is for old-fashion, but I still feel it is complex. So I don't abandon any idea to do with  ManagedInstallerClass. I just want to add description to the code.

Comment: Right.  If you're just wanting to work within the code as described, you'll need to import the `ChangeServiceConfig2` call just like you did with `OpenSCManager`, `CreateService`, etc.  Then call it with the  parameters as described in the answer.  That should do it.

Answer (score 11):

The answered code does not work.  This is a version that does work for me:

```
const int SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION = 0x01;

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ChangeServiceConfig2(IntPtr hService, int dwInfoLevel, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref SERVICE_DESCRIPTION lpInfo);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct SERVICE_DESCRIPTION
{
    public string lpDescription;
}

var pinfo = new SERVICE_DESCRIPTION
{
    lpDescription = "My Service Description"
};

ChangeServiceConfig2(service, SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, ref pinfo);
```

Comment: worked for me - VS 2015 targeting FW 4.0 today.
Note: you have to open the service with ChangeConfig right:
    IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, ServiceName, ServiceRights.QueryStatus | ServiceRights.ChangeConfig);

Comment: after trying out many things, this actually works !